# code igniter convert form dropdown into regular select box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, dropdownbox

i am trying to convert my form code into regular select box .. but it work in form_dropdown and not in regular select box .. i think i am doing something wrong .. actually i am new in code igniter ..

this is my two drop down select boxes.. the logic is actually implemented in that way that it show the options in second dropdown based on the previous dropdown ..

```
                 <!-- Categories -->
        <?php $items['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>

   Select a Category: 
<?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#','id="category"  class = "cho"');?>


        <!-- end of Categories -->

        <!-- Items -->
        Items: </label>

<?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3 , '#', 'id="items" class="cho"'); ?>
                <br />


        <!-- end of Items -->
```

items are coming based on the categories ..i just want them to convert these two select or dropdown  boxes into regular html way ..

and this is my javascript

```
       <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
         $(document).ready(function(){       
            $('#category').change(function(){ 

        if (document.getElementById('items_chzn') != undefined) {
            $("#items_chzn").remove();
            $("#items").attr("class","");
            //$("#items").show();         
        }

        $("#items > option").remove(); 
        var category_id = $('#category').val();  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id,

            success: function(items) 
            {
                $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(item_id);
                    opt.text(item_name);
                    $('#items').append(opt); 
                });

                //alert("applying plugin");
                $('#items').chosen({no_results_text: "No results matched"});
            }

        });

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to change it to regular html way ..when u have it working in CI way... anyways

try this

**categories**

```
 <select name="cat_id" id="category"  class = "cho">
   <?php foreach($records2 as $row){?>  //loop through your categories option  here
     <option value="<?php echo $row['value']?>"><?php echo $row['text']?></option>
  <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

**Items**

```
 <select name="item_id" id="items" class="cho">
  //optional <?php foreach($records3 as $row){?>  //since this is dynamic i don't think u need options here
     <option value="<?php echo $row['value']?>"><?php echo $row['text']?></option>
  <?php } ?> // optional ends
 </select>
```

**updated**

for CI form multiselect

```
$selectmultioption= array('//value1 of option you want to select', '//value2 of option you  want to select');
<?php echo form_multiselect('cat_id[]', $records2, $selectmultioption ,'id="category"  class = "cho"');?>
```

Comment: because i want to select the default text at the start but it didnt work in CI way and the next thing i want to implement the select multiple for this ... which is either  dont know how to do that in that way .. thats why ...if you can do both These functions in CI's way then illbe very thankful to you

Comment: well your above code didnt work for me ..if i go for  the categories dropdown one , it is showing  only the first alphabet. so i didnt try the next one . i think may b there is some mistake u r doing ..

Comment: ok let me try now your updated answer .. let me see how it works

Comment: well first i didnt get this line that what should i write in the array .. array('//value1 of option you want to select', '//value2 of option you  want to select');  and the second thing is this its not becoming a dropdown box .. and the last thing please if you write your suggested code within my code then it'll b get easy for me to check and then reply you quick

Comment: ok instead of this  `'//value1 of option you want to select', '//value2 of option you want to select'` you write your default valkue to be loaded...and above updated code you just need to repalce your `form_dropdown` with my code